# style/position video when playing in picture-in-picture mode

Tags: css, video, picture-in-picture

1. When playing html5 video in picture in picture mode it will remember its last position where it played last time
   Is there a way to force the picture in picture window to appear at some specific position?
2. CSS pseudo-class ":picture-in-picture" does not have any effect , is this working?
   found only this example
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:picture-in-picture

and it is not very clear with todo with it. My Idea tells that ":picture-in-picture" is "Unknown pseudo selector"

Comment: Same [problem here](https://github.com/livekit/livekit-react/issues/81#issuecomment-1207443288). Looking forward to anybody reporting back what's up with that pseudo class – or maybe the MDN article needs to be changed?